# Displaying data from the database (MERN)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, mern

I added photos to the MongoDB database using multer and I want to display them now, the console data looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lArg.png)

Code frontend app:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            profileImg: '',
            image:[]
            
        }
    }
```

```
  async fetchImage(){
        var a = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api');
        const img = a.data;
        this.setState({text:[img.users]})
        console.log("Dane stanu: " + this.state.image)
    }

And i try to map this:
```

```
{this.state.image.map(person => <li key={person._id}><img src={person.profileImg} alt="błąd"/></li>)}
```

but nothing shows up,please help me find the bug

EDIT: I add fetchImage() in componentDidMount()

```
 componentDidMount()
    {
        this.fetchImage();
    }
```

Comment: provide styling to the image.

Comment: @UmairRiaz i did it but still the same result
`code <img style={{width:'100px', height:'100px'}} src={person.profileImg} alt="błąd"/> `

Answer (score 0):

I send image data from server to client in body this way:

```
fs.readFile(slidePath, (err, buf) => {
client.send(JSON.stringify({img: buf.toString('base64')})]
```

On react client I catch it this way:

```
<img src=`data:image/jpg;base64,${postData.img}`>
```